# CSS - Why cannot div wrap h1 element?

Tags: css

```
<div id="title">
    <h1>
        Title
    </h1>
</div>
```

I know there is some default margin along with `h1` tag.  When I check it out with chrome dev tools, I find that the `div` part is smaller than `h1` part(the highlighted zone of `h1` is larger than `div`). It seems `div` does not include the margin of `h1`, can anyone tell me why ?

Comment: [Margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/margin_collapsing)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [2.1 Spec:](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)

> "The top margin of an in-flow block element collapses with its first in-flow block-level child's top margin if the element has no top border, no top padding, and the child has no clearance."

---

Also:

- Floated elements' margins never collapse, not even with in-flow block descendants
- Inline-block elements' margins never collapse, not even with in-flow block descendants
- Block containers with an `overflow` property value other than `visible` do not have collapsing margins, not even with in-flow block descendants
- The margins of absolutely/fixed positioned elements do not collapse, not even with in-flow descendants
- The margins of adjacent flex items don't collapse
- Horizontal margins never collapse

Regarding negative margin collapsing, the [2.1 Spec states](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins):

> "In the case of negative margins, the maximum of the absolute values of the negative adjoining margins is deducted from the maximum of the positive adjoining margins. If there are no positive margins, the maximum of the absolute values of the adjoining margins is deducted from zero."